# Symfony DataMapper not updating object

Tags: forms, symfony

I'm using a DataMapper as per docs: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_mappers.html to update a date from 1 of 3 fields in the form:

**Form Class**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('period_start_daily', DateType::class, [
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'label' => 'Day',
            'html5' => false,
            'attr' => ['class' => 'js-datepicker'],
            'mapped' => false,
            'required' => false
        ])
        ->add('period_start_weekly', DateType::class, [
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'label' => 'Week',
            'html5' => false,
            'attr' => ['class' => 'js-datepicker'],
            'mapped' => false,
            'required' => false
        ])
        ->add('period_start_monthly', ChoiceType::class, [
            'required' => true,
            'label' => 'Month',
            'choice_loader' => new CallbackChoiceLoader(function () {
                $months = [];
                for ($i = 0; $i <= 12; $i++) {
                    $month = strtotime('first day of this month + ' . $i . ' months');
                    $months[date('M Y', $month)] = date('Y-m-d', $month);
                }
                return $months;
            }),
            'mapped' => false,
            'required' => false
        ])
...
$builder
        ->setDataMapper($this);
...
public function mapFormsToData($forms, &$data)
{
    /** @var FormInterface[] $forms */
    $forms = iterator_to_array($forms);

    switch (intval($forms['Type']->getViewData())){
        case 1:
            $start = $forms['period_start_daily']->getNormData();
            $end = clone $start;

            break;
        case 2:
            $start = $forms['period_start_weekly']->getNormData();
            $end = clone $start;
            $end->add(new \DateInterval('P6D'));
            break;
        case 3:
            $start = $forms['period_start_daily']->getNormData();
            $end = (new \DateTime(
                strtotime($this->getData()['period_start_monthly']->format('Y-m-d').' last day of month')
            ));
            break;
    }
    $data = (new DataSet())
        ->setPeriodStart($start)
        ->setPeriodEnd($end)
        ->setType($forms['Type']->getNormData())
        ->setUpload($forms['upload']->getNormData());
```

**Controller**

```
    $form = $this->createForm(DataSetType::class, $dataset);

    $form->handleRequest($request->getCurrentRequest());

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
        $dataset
            ->setPeriodStart($form->getNormData()->getPeriodStart())
            ->setPeriodEnd($form->getNormData()->getPeriodEnd());
        $dataset->setType($form->getNormData()->getType());
        $dataset->setActive(false);
        $dataset->setUpload($form->getNormData()->getUpload());
        $dataset->getPeriodStart()->setTime(0, 0, 0);
        $dataset->getPeriodEnd()->setTime(0, 0, 0);

        $em->persist($dataset);
        $em->flush();
```

I expected the DataMapper to update my object directly, however I still have to copy over the data from $form->getNormData().

Symfony version is 4.2

Comment: The issue might be that you reassign $data. Can you push the code to GitHub so we can debug it with Xdebug?

Comment: Thank you very much for the offer. It is here https://github.com/jochendaum/datamappernotworking I have not crested fixtures, just a dump of 2 tables in dump.sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded [your project](https://github.com/jochendaum/datamappernotworking) to debug it and I found a mistake - it was hard to detect :) I started thinking that there might be something wrong with Symfony 4 but not. Everything is fine and everything works fine.

Look:

[image]

> spl_object_hash — Return hash id for given object
>
> This function returns a unique identifier for the object. This id can be used as a hash key for storing objects, or for identifying an object, as long as the object is not destroyed. Once the object is destroyed, its hash may be reused for other objects.

`$beforeHash` and `$afterHash` have different values - therefore, it's not the same object

In `DataSetType.php`(line 138) you create new instance of `DataSet` losing a reference to previous object passed as the second parameter in `mapFormsToData`:

[image]

You should modify object in `$data` parameter instead creating new instance of `DataSet`.

**Step 1:**

Change this code:

```
$data = (new DataSet())
        ->setPeriodStart($start)
        ->setPeriodEnd($end)
        ->setType($forms['Type']->getNormData())
        ->setUpload($forms['upload']->getNormData())
        ->setActive($forms['active']->getNormData())
    ;
```

To this piece of code:

```
$data->setPeriodStart($start)
     ->setPeriodEnd($end)
     ->setType($forms['Type']->getNormData())
     ->setUpload($forms['upload']->getNormData())
     ->setActive($forms['active']->getNormData());
```

**Step 2:**

Remove unnecessary code from your controller. `create` method should look like this:

```
public function create(RequestStack $request)
{
    $dataset = new DataSet();

    $form = $this->createForm(DataSetType::class, $dataset);

    $form->handleRequest($request->getCurrentRequest());

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($dataset);
        $em->flush();

        if ($dataset->getUpload()) {
            $em->getRepository('App:DataSet')
                ->disableUploadOthers($dataset->getId(), $dataset->getType());
        }
        $this->addFlash('success', 'Dataset created.');
        return $this->redirectToRoute('dataset_index');
    }

    return $this->render('dataset/create.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ]);
}
```

Values in `$dataset` must change without your help :)

---

[Documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_mappers.html) can be a bit confusing but note that the [example from documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_mappers.html) is based on an **immutable object**

[image]

By the way - it would be good to extend the documentation and show how DataMapper works with Doctrine models...